# Flutter update the listview in a widget from another wideget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 screens in my application "Principal.dart" "ListUsers.dart" and "Config.dart".

when the user opens the filter settings screen and saves, the ListUsers.dart screen is reloaded again to make a new API call with the new filters and update the ListView

on the main screen "Principal.dart" I have an appBar and I call the screen that has the ListView "ListUser.dart"

Principal.dart

```
class Principal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrincipalState createState() => _PrincipalState();
}

class _PrincipalState extends State<Principal> {
  ListaUsers listaUsersPage;
  Widget currentPage;

  reloadDeps() {
    this.callback(new ListaUsers());
  }

  _abreConfig(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return ConfigForm(onFunc: reloadDeps);
        });
  }

  void callback(Widget nextPage) {
    setState(() {
      this.currentPage = nextPage; // **nothing happens**
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listaUsersPage = ListaUsers();
    currentPage = listaUsersPage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My app"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _abreConfig(context);
                });
              },
            ),
        body: currentPage);
  }
}
```

My ListUsers.dart

```
class ListaUsers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListaUsersState createState() => _ListaUsersState();
}

class _ListaUsersState extends State<ListaUsers> {
  bool bCarregando = true;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<Users> listaUsersLista = [];

  _listaUsers() async {
    setState(() {
      bCarregando = true;
    });
    listaUsersLista = await ApiUsers.listaUsers(); //return data from API
    setState(() {
      bCarregando = false;
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _listaUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (bCarregando == true)
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listaUsersLista.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Users reg = listaUsersLista[index];
              return Dismissible(
                key: ValueKey(reg.id),
                onDismissed: (direction) async {
                  if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                  }
                  if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                  }
                },
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListaUsersItem(items: reg),
              );
            });
  }
}
```

my Config.dart

```
class ConfigForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function() onFunc;
  const ConfigForm({Key key, this.onFunc}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ConfigFormState createState() => _ConfigFormState();
}

class _ConfigFormState extends State<ConfigForm> {

  _salvaConfig() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("ufFiltro", Session.shared.ufFiltro);

    widget.onFunc();

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Configurações salvas com sucesso!")));

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        //...
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Aplicar filtros",
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _salvaConfig)
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

How can I make this work, or should I use another approach for the result I need?
thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is to implement a state management solution. I recommend GetX, Riverpod or Provider, in that order (just personal preference, can't go wrong with either). General idea here would be have your `Listview.builder` build based on a list that lives in a state management class, that can trigger a rebuild based on an updated state of the list. Any state management solution will allow you to do that.

Comment: @Loren.A Thanks for the guidance, I'm reading about it right now.

Comment: @Loren.A I'm using getX and got the result I wanted, I don't know if in the best way, but I did, and I loved it, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out.